# ¿Cómo editar, insertar y eliminar items de un `RecyclerView` dentro de un `ViewPager`?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Tengo un proyecto que utiliza, `TabLayout`, `ViewPager` y `RecyclerView`, lo que necesito hacer es controlar los Tabs y los items del `RecyclerView` dinamicamente, que desde un boton fuera  del `ViewPager` se Edite, inserte y eliminen items dentro del `RecyclerView`(el cual esta dentro del ViewPager).

Los items que van dentro del `RecyclerView` no son imagenes, son texto.

¿Es posible hacer eso?, muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda... todo punto de vista lo agradezco.

Adiciono la estructura del proyecto en la siguiente imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: claro que es posible todo lo que comentas, que parte de este proyecto tienes realizada? Me parece es un poquitino amplia la pregunta ya que son varias cosas.

Comment: Existen muchas respuestas posibles, o las buenas respuestas son demasiado extensas para este formato. Añade detalles para reducir el conjunto de respuestas o separar un problema que se puede responder en pocos párrafos.

Comment: Gracias,tengo en código laEstructura asi comoEsta en la imagen, cada Tab carga un viewPager con un RecyclerView y unos items dentro, el tema es que cuando coloco un boton con un código de modificar un item dentro del RecyclerView sí me loLogra modificar, peroCuando cambio de Tab's y vuelvo al que había modificado me carga en el RecyclerView algo que no es,ejemplo:TengoCargados  dinámicamente 4 Tab's, cuando estoy en el 2tab y yo actualizo un valor con un boton me loActualiza, pero cuando me paso al 4tab y vuelvo a seleccionar el 2tab no meCarga el 2tab, lo que me hace esCargar la info del 1tab

Comment: Creo que se necesitaría ver el código para poder ayudarte. Si dices que lo tienes implementado, pero que algo falla cuando vuelves, es porque algo no ejecutas bien. Deja un link con el proyecto o agrega el código a la pregunta, por lo menos el del `RecyclerAdapter` y el de la tab.

Answer (score 1):

Si bien la pregunta es un poco amplia empezaría por justamente simplificar el tema.
Para empezar, los botones van fuera del RecyclerView por lo que en el xml sería algo como (tendrías una de esta por cada tab)

`

```
<Button android:id="@+id/BtnInsertar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/insertar" />

<Button android:id="@+id/BtnEliminar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/BtnInsertar"
    android:text="@string/eliminar" />

<Button android:id="@+id/BtnMover"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/BtnEliminar"
    android:text="@string/mover" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RecView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/BtnInsertar"/>
```

`

Ahora, desde la clase donde estableces el valor del adaptador y el RecyclerView supongamos que tenés algo como

```
datos = new ArrayList<ClaseModeloDelRV>();
```

entonces el botón de eliminar por ejemplo sería algo como :

```
    btnEliminar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BtnEliminar);

    btnEliminar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            datos.remove(1);
            adaptador.notifyItemRemoved(1);
        }
    });
```

El cuidado que tendría es que el arraylist no se cargue solo cada vez que se selecciona el tab así podes conservar los dato manejados en el arraylist.

Quizás ya hiciste algo de esto pero para achicar el rango de la pregunta pareció bueno hacerlo.